# Get AWS Availability zone info inside a machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there an AWS API to hit and get the availability zone of the current machine where the code is running? I tried to check if such ENV variable is set automatically by AWS but couldn't find such a thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current AZ of the instance using [Instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html).

For example:

```
AZ=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)

echo ${AZ}
```

will output (example):

```
us-east-1e
```